# Grant access to user for all user folders and subfolders in c:/users

Tags: windows, file-permissions

We have an RDS server with dozens of user profiles and I am trying to run cleanup scripts to get rid of some old software folders from the users C:\users*username\appdata\local\softwarenamedfolder
However I get access denied errors when trying to run my script
When I try to browse to said folders it gives me a popup saying I have no permissions click continue to get them

I tried running the following in powershell

```
icacls "C:\users" /grant "Domain Admins":F /t
```

and now it no longer pops up when clicking the username in C:\users, however the appdata folders for each user still do not have the permission set

What can I use to iterate through EVERY SINGLE FOLDER in C:\users and add the domain admins group will full control?

Comment: Won't help, because when you're using the GUI or an unelevated command line your membership of the Domain Admins group is disabled by User Account Control (UAC).   See, e.g., [this article](https://notesbytom.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/uac-blocks-administrators-and-domain-admins-groups/).  Your scripts should work as-is, without making any permissions changes, provided you run them from an elevated (run "as administrator") command prompt.  (Of course that assumes there is nothing unusual about the permissions on your server.)

Answer (score 0):

1) This is bad practice.
2) I do something similar where I give a backup administrator rights to the users folders so that I can do granular restore using Windows Backup. Just do what you're doing (more or less) but put it in a login script and the user themselves will run the script for you on login or as a scheduled task.
Or add a line to give admins rights to each users folder on login, then automate a task that will do your cleanup task.